# How force:recordData identifies the sObject type?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-data-service

In lightning:recordForm we give objectAPIName but in force:recordForm we do not specify any such attribute So, **How does force:recordData identify the sObjectType?**

Assuming there is no value for recordId attribute in case of creating a new record.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to create record by using `force:recordData` you don't need pass value for `recordId` attribute in `force:recordData` , that's how LDS detect it's for New record action.

> How does force:recordData identify the sObjectType?

you to have to use `getNewRecord` method for loads the form and set to requested `targetRecord` attribute value, usually this method calls from doinit method. here is example code below.

cmp

```
 <aura:attribute name="newContact" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="simpleNewContact" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="newContactError" type="String"/>

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

<force:recordData aura:id="contactRecordCreator" 
                  layoutType="FULL"
                  targetRecord="{!v.newContact}"
                  targetFields="{!v.simpleNewContact}"
                  targetError="{!v.newContactError}" />
 <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small">              
            <lightning:input aura:id="contactField" label="Last Name" value="{!v.simpleNewContact.LastName}"/>                
            <br/>
            <lightning:button label="Save Contact" variant="brand" onclick="{!c.handleSaveContact}"/>
        </div>
```

controller.js

```
({
doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
    // Prepare a new record from template
    component.find("contactRecordCreator").getNewRecord(
        "Contact", // sObject type (objectApiName)
        null,      // recordTypeId
        false,     // skip cache?
        $A.getCallback(function() {
            var rec = component.get("v.newContact");
            var error = component.get("v.newContactError");
            if(error || (rec === null)) {
                // handle error
            }
            console.log("Record template initialized: " + rec.apiName);
        })
    );
},
// for create new contact record
handleSaveContact: function(component, event, helper) {
    if(helper.validateContactForm(component)) {            
        component.find("contactRecordCreator").saveRecord(function(saveResult) {
            if (saveResult.state === "SUCCESS" || saveResult.state === "DRAFT") {
                // record is saved successfully                

            } else if (saveResult.state === "INCOMPLETE") {
                // handle the incomplete state
                console.log("User is offline, device doesn't support drafts.");
            } else if (saveResult.state === "ERROR") {
                // handle the error state
                console.log('Problem saving contact, error: ' + 
     JSON.stringify(saveResult.error));
            } else {
                console.log('Unknown problem, state: ' + saveResult.state + ', error: ' + JSON.stringify(saveResult.error));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

})